# Forget / Remove Stored WiFi Network in iOS Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, wifi

Since adding WiFi Network Programmatically in iOS is nearly impossible without jailbreaking the Iphone :(

**Is it possible to Forget / Remove an already stored WiFi Network Programmatically with SWIFT or Objective-C without jailbreaking the iphone?**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, as this is not something done in the scope of an application.
And if it was possible, it seems like a sure way to not get your app approve for the App Store.

Comment: Thanks, Is this still the case in 2020?